# Древнерусское "наследие"

Tags: старославянский

Попалось в интернете вот такое вот высказывание:
*"Дорогия друзья, почему мы забываем русский язык?

Где эти слова, как сызмальства, недалече?

Почему мы говорим гламурная чикса? – Красна девица.

Не харя, а лик.

Не очкую, а робею.

И вообще, с древнерусского слово "задница" переводится, как наследие".*
Скажите, пожалуйста, правда ли написана в последней строчке? А то мне как-то не очень верится.

Comment: Стрескать бутылку водки в один лик... Нет, не звучит как-то...

Comment: А по-моему, как раз шикарно звучит. Надо бы запомнить)))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все о древнерусской заднице :

[image: Задница] 
"спор об оставшемся наследстве"
http://www.orthodic.org/cs/З/2

> ***Задница***
> термин древнерусского гражданского права, встречающийся в "Русской Правде" и означающий наследство (в том же смысле употребляется иногда статок). З. открывается в "Русской Правде" смертью отца семейства и продолжается смертью матери; при этом наблюдается резкая разница между смердьею и боярскою (или дружинною) З. Первую получают только сыновья умершего, если сыновей нет, то наследует князь, выдавая часть на незамужних дочерей, вторая равно получается как сыновьями, так и, за отсутствием последних, дочерьми (сестры при братьях не наследницы; братья отдают их замуж с приданым, смотря по средствам). Вдова после мужа не наследница; она или получает в полную собственность то, что на нее взложил муж при жизни, или же, если по смерти мужа решает вдовствовать, то получает часть по закону. Дети от рабы З. не имеют, но получают свободу вместе с матерью. "Матерняя часть" может быть завещана безразлично и сыновьям, и дочерям; если же мать умрет "без языка", не распорядившись, то эта часть становится З. того из детей, у которого она жила и кормилась. Детиз от разных отцов и одной матери (единоутробные) получают задницы каждый после своего отца. Младший сын по закону наследует отцовский двор под условием дележа З. между всеми сыновьями поровну, за выделом из последней лишь части по душе. Устанавливая смердью и боярскую З., "Русская Правда" различает наследование по закону и наследование с "ряда", т. е. договора при жизни завещателя, и знает наследование только по прямой нисходящей линии. Братьев при случае отсутствия "ряда" делит в случае спора княжеский детский, получающий с них за то гривну кун. Из других памятников права видно, однако, что бывали случаи наследования боковых родственников, о которых ничего не знает "Русская Правда". Церковный устав св. Владимира прямо говорит, что тяжба о З. входит в сферу церковных судов, а не светских. Объяснение этого противоречия стоит в связи с общим вопросом об отношении "Русской Правды" к современной ей судебной практике. См. "Русскую Правду" по Троицкому списку, ст. 85-89, 92-98, 100, церковные уставы Владимира, Ярослава и Всеволода и договор смоленского кн. Мстислава Давидовича с немцами в редакциях 1229 и 1230 г. Выморочное имущество называлось не З., а "безатщина" (см. этот термин в церковном уставе Ярослава I). **Наследник в Кормчей XVI в. обозначается термином задъничник.**
>
> Энциклопедический словарь Ф.А. Брокгауза и И.А. Ефрона.
>
> Н. С. Лесков. Письма Л. Н. Толстому (1887-1894)
> 2) Известно ли Вам, что на старом языке у нас «наследство» называлось «задница»?